# How to change the color of a rectangle after a click?

Tags: c++, qt

I wrote code that displays a 5x5 rectangle:

```
void PrintRectangle::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    int xpos=20;
    int ypos=20;
    int recWidth=50;
    int recHeight=50;
    int y=20;

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        ypos=20;
        p.fillRect(xpos,ypos,recWidth,recHeight,Qt::red);

        for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
           p.fillRect(xpos,ypos,recWidth,recHeight,Qt::red);
           ypos+=60;
        }
        xpos+=60;
    }
}
```

This works fine. How to implement a function that changes the color of a clicked rectangle? Should I store that rectangle in a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re implement

```
virtual void    mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
```

with event you can get the position of click and check which box need color change. After that you call update() for widget.

Following code will paint the clicked cell in green and others in red.

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
    void mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent* ev);

private:
    void resetClickedIndex();
    void updateIndexFromPoint( const QPoint& point);
private:
    int mXIndex;
    int mYIndex;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"

#include <QPainter>
#include <QMouseEvent>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent)
{
    resetClickedIndex();
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
}

void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    int xpos=20;
    int ypos=20;
    int recWidth=50;
    int recHeight=50;
    int y=20;

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        ypos=20;
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            QColor color = Qt::red;
            if( i == mXIndex && j == mYIndex )
            {
                color = Qt::green;
            }
           p.fillRect(xpos,ypos,recWidth,recHeight,color);
           ypos+=60;
        }
        xpos+=60;
    }
}

void Widget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    QPoint point = ev->pos();
    updateIndexFromPoint( point );
    update();
}

void Widget::resetClickedIndex()
{
    mXIndex = -1;
    mYIndex = -1;
}

void Widget::updateIndexFromPoint(const QPoint &point)
{
    int x = point.x() - 20;
    int y = point.y() - 20;

    if( ( (x >= 0 )  && ( x <= 300) ) && ( (y >= 0 )  && ( y <= 300) ) )
    {
        mXIndex = x / 60; //rec width + spacing
        mYIndex = y / 60; //rec height + spacing
    }
    else
    {
        resetClickedIndex();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have it, but I don't known how to store all rectangle, next delete color and make another color.

Comment: Right. Note that update() invokes a paintEvent. So, if above code (paintEvent()) reimplemented to update, it would most likely have cyclic updates. - Just implement in mousePressEvent like sanjay stated.

Comment: @lukassz  check the updated code, it will paint the clicked cell in green, other cell in red. I hope that it solve you problem. If solved please mark it solved.

Comment: @sanjay ok it works, but I woudl like to click many rectangle eg. 2 or 5, not only one and after reclick on clicked rectangle change color back to red, maybe QMap to store this rectangle?